# how to prove that arc length formula is equal to distance formula

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

$$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2} = \int_x^{x_1} \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}\right)^2}$$

During math class, my teacher mentioned the distance formula and he said that this formula on the right can calculate distance between 2 points (or a line). I know a bit of calc and so I thought of the arc length equation and I wanted to see if they were equal or not.

I attempted to take the derivative on both sides but that wouldn't work because there are 2 variables and you can only take the derivative of 1 variable. so I got very confused but I know that they should be equal.

My question is how do you prove that these 2 equations are equal or different?

thx in advanced

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a tutorial on typesetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are both constants so

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)^2} \:dt = (x_2-x_1)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)^2} = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The straight line

$$y=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)+y_1$$

can be parametrized by

$$s(t)=\left(t, \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(t-x_1)+y_1\right)$$

with $t\in(x_1,x_2)$ then

$$|s’(t)|=\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)^2}$$

from which the result follows.